# Confused about そうでおられます

Tags: meaning

> ……隠し事が苦手そうでおられますから。

I'm a bit confused about the end of this sentence. I would have thought that 隠し事が下手そうですから would be the only way of closing this particular sentence. I usually understand おる as a polite subtitute of いる but in this case I'm not sure how to interpret it. How does that work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「おられます」 means the same thing as 「いらっしゃいます」.  It is a politer and more respectful form of 「いる」 or 「います」.

Some might argue that 「おられます」 is an incorrect honorific form, but the truth is that you will hear it said quite often.　You will hear both 「おられる」 and 「あられる」 used to talk about people higher in status than the speakers.  Again, those might also be considered incorrect, but they are in active use in formal speech.

> "Since it seems rather difficult for you to keep secrets, sir/ma'am ..."

Depending on the context, the speaker may be referring to a third person.

Comment: So, if we were to make the sentence less polite, what would that be ? 下手そうである ? でおられます is である, right ?

Comment: Far less polite would be 苦手そうだから, followed by 苦手そうですから or 苦手そうであるから.　You would not use those to refer to your superiors, of course.